# Does CCAvenue allow payment gateway to be used on 2 different domains?

Tags: payment-gateway, ccavenue

Hello All i have payment gateway integrated on one of my domain. Can the same be integrated on my other domain as well. I am using CCAvenue payment gateway.

Comment: i have same problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes,

CCAvenue can support multiple domains. but you have to check code with the particular platform.

here you can read this all things https://www.ccavenue.com/ccavenue_index.jsp#

Comment: Could't get help from this answer, there is no place on the website so i can add new domains.

Comment: I am not having the access of CCAvenue Admin Pandel, but you can go and look into the admin panel provided to you by CCAvenue Team and you can do all these type of customisation there. Some are pre available for some type of customisation you have to contact with the Tech Team, they will provide you all the info.
but yes you can add multiple domains and receive payments as well.